# Lock screen after blanking with gnome-screensaver and XFCE

Tags: xfce, screensaver

I'm using XFCE4 with Fedora 18 and replaced `xscreensaver` with `gnome-screensaver`. I have `gnome-screensaver` checked in session and startup and `xscreensaver` unchecked.

By using power manager, I have configured my machine to blank screen after a few minutes. What I want to accomplish is lock the screen after waking up from these blank screens, and that is currently not working with my setup.

The problem with gnome-screensaver is that it lacks tools to configure basic things like how long it should wait to fire screensaver. `xscreensaver` can be configured to 'go screensaver after x minutes and turn lock screen on', but `gnome-screensaver` has to equivalent configuration tool. what I have is 'Session and Startup' and 'power manager' tools, and they don't have an option to 'lock screen after waking back from blank screen'(they do have one for suspend/hibernation though.).

What should I do? I don't really go with `xscreensaver`.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with xfce, but does `qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock` work (kde version)? on Gnome you use `qdbus org.gnome.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock`. You may have to type `qdbus | grep -i screensaver` to find your specific variation.

Comment: Rereading your question, I realize this probably doesn't answer your question as it works from command line only.